# HTML pseudo elements placed over actual child nodes

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

For some reason, when an element's pseudo child node is added, its z-index is higher than its child nodes, even though its a `::before` element, which appears before the relative child nodes, but doesn't display that way. Why does this happen, and is there a way to fix it?

Here's an example where the child `<h1>` node *should* appear as if it's hovering over the black pseudo element, but that isn't the case.

https://jsfiddle.net/9u33vko0/

Is my understanding just fundamentally wrong?

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1> <!-- should appear above the black ::before element -->
    Hello, World!
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the `:before` pseudo element appears *before* the `h1` element in the DOM, it will still overlap the `h1` element because it [establishes a stacking context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) due to the fact that it is positioned (with `position: absolute`).

Here is a relevant quote from the [CSS2 specification on stacking contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) (painting order; point 8)

> All positioned descendants with `z-index: auto` or `z-index: 0`, in tree order. For those with `z-index: auto`, treat the element as if it created a new stacking context ...

Therefore you could establish a stacking context with the `h1` element by positioning it (i.e., by adding `position: relative`). In doing so, the `h1` element will be placed above the `:before` pseudo element because it appears after the pseudo element in the DOM and both elements are positioned with a `z-index` of `auto`.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/5zgh91hu/)

```
h1 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</div>
```

Of course, you could also just give the pseudo element a negative `z-index`, but that's besides the point. When it comes down to it, establishing a stacking context is enough since the `:before` pseudo element appears before the `h1` element in the DOM (as you have already pointed out).

Comment: Beat me to it. Very well explained. +1